# List creation and object initializers

Tags: c#

I'm struggling to get my head around what's happening with the List in the example below:

```
public class DataObject
{
    public List<object> SomeObjects { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var dataObj = new DataObject()
                          {
                              SomeObjects = { new object() },
                          };

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Creation of `dataOjb` obviously fails because the `SomeObjects` property hasn't been instantiated. I assume that there's no compile error because `DataObject` could have a constructor that instantiated `SomeObjects`. Given that, if I attempt to do something like:

```
List<int> SomeObjects;
SomeObjects = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

This obviously doesn't work, and neither does:

```
List<int> SomeObjects = new List<int>();
SomeObjects = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

So to get to my actual question, what is that called in the first object initializer (I've tried looking it up and can't find it), why does it behave differently, and are there other places it can be used like this?

Comment: Down voters, reasons? It doesn't seem constructive, how would I know what was wrong with my question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So to get to my actual question, what is that called in the first object initializer

This is the equivalent code:

```
var tmp = new DataObject();
tmp.SomeObjects.Add(new object());
var dataObj = tmp;
```

(And the second line fails due to `tmp.SomeObjects` being null in your case, obviously.)

This `= { ... }` syntax is *only* applicable within object initializers, which is why your latter two code snippets are invalid.

More specifically - and in specification terminology - a *member-initializer* is of the form

```
identifier = initializer-value
```

where *initializer-value* is one of *expression* or *object-or-collection-initializer*. This isn't just applicable for collections though... you can set properties of existing members, too:

```
var foo = new Foo {
    Bar = {
        X = 2,
        Y = 3
    }
};
```

which is equivalent to:

```
var tmp = new Foo();
tmp.Bar.X = 2;
tmp.Bar.Y = 3;
var foo = tmp;
```

Comment: Thanks, Jon. This was exactly what I wanted to know.